# Active directory to ldap synchronization

Tags: active-directory, debian, ldap, openldap, synchronization

I have two LDAP servers. First is Active Directory and second is openLDAP. I need setup between these servers.
Is here anybody, who know, how to do it?

I tried to use this [link for tutorial](https://camratus.com/blog/OpenLdap_%E2%80%93_LSC_%E2%80%93_Active_Directory_sync_and_login_pass-through-12), but I found problem. When I started migration with the command, i got response this:

```
Error: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.xml.bind.Messages, locale en_US
```

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.xml.bind.Messages, locale en_US
at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lsc works only with jdk8, By installing openjdk-8-jdk should fix the issue.